# Is the support API still the way to go for new apps?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I see the official documentation uses the support API in its documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

As a newbie in Android I have some questions.

Is is okay to aim for the API level higher than 11 devices only ?

In that case, can I still skip using the support API mentioned there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Min version depends upon your target audience. From a development standpoint the newer API's have more features. You can see version statistics [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone).

At this points devices using API 11 are going to be pretty old and may not be your target audicance.

The newest design standards by Google is to use Material Design found in the `appcompat-v7` support library

There are several other support libraries for backports of components
`design` For Floating Action Button & Snackbars
`cardview` for cardviews
`recyclerview` for efficient lists of items

Also of note the latest version of `AppComapt` `22.2.0` now uses `Toolbar` instead of `ActionBar` (you can set a toolbar to be used as an 1Actionbar`)

**Update**

If you want to use [Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) (recommended) but still support older version of Android here are some updates from the action bar guide you linked.

```
// Extend AppComaptActivity instead of Activity
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectivityService.ConnectivityListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
    // Set the toolbar defined in your layout as the ActionBar
    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
}
```

One final difference is that your app theme should be (or extend) some variant that does not include an action bar (e.g `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`)

There are plenty of other guides on using AppCompat and Material Design, the linked ActionBar guide is correct if you are building a pre API 21 app without using AppComapt.

Comment: If Toolbar replaces ActionBar now then may we say this training guide is not up to date ? http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Comment: Yes, but it it has a lot of useful information as well. I will update my answer to include some of the differences.

Comment: I wonder what you mean  by "a pre API 21". What would be a post API 21 ? Also, shall I understand you highly recommend using AppCompat in post API 21 environment ?

Comment: By pre API 21 I mean a project with a minVersion < 21. In API 21 (a.k.a lollipop) there were major updates to the SDK and design standards. The AppCompat library (v21+) was updated to include some of those features because the main SDK (i.e. not AppCompat) version of those features are not available until the minSdk of your project is at least 21. AppCompat is essentially a backport of  key (not all) new features to older version of Android.

Comment: All right. So, some choose to have a min sdk higher than 21 ? Wow... I thought we were advised to allow for lower ones. For my own new app I went for a min sdk of 14 and a target sdk of 21. What would be your choice if going for a new app ?

Comment: I would probably go with minSdk 16 (That gets 89% of current devices and will go up as people upgrade). And use AppCompat v7 (along with design and recycler view libraires) to get material design support.

Answer (score 2):

> Is is okay to aim for the API level higher than 11 devices only ?

Yes.

> I still skip using the support API mentioned there ?

I assume you are referring to `appcompat-v7` for the action bar backport. You do not have to use this.

Some other libraries (e.g., Android Design Support library) presently require you to use `appcompat-v7` for certain things. `appcompat-v7` also gives you aspects of the Material Design aesthetic on older devices, in terms of the action bar and the tinting of some widgets for your brand's colors. If those features are of interest to you, you can certainly use `appcompat-v7` if you wish.